# Is there a single function that concat a string to every entry in a list?

Tags: string, list, emacs, elisp

```el
(setq a '("bar" "baz" "barz"))
(setq prefix "foo")

;; Expected result
==> ("foobar" "foobaz" "foobarz")
```

I have been doing this by `dolist` or iterating through `car`. Is there a single function doing the same job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a *single* function, but I would use:

```el
(mapcar (apply-partially #'concat prefix) a)
```

There are lots of ways you could do this, though, and there's probably nothing particularly wrong with what you were doing.